# CSS select + select How to get first select

Tags: html, css, symfony-1.4

Please help me!!

Cant I get first select in this case:

```
select+select{
   width: 50%;
}
```

I want to set the same width both select controls.

Note: I can't set a different class to the select because this is a widget HTML that is rendered by symfony ->render().

```
<div>
  <select>
    <option>...</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option>...</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

PD: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set both select's to the same width use:

```
select { width: 50% }
```

Your example set's the width to 50% on the second select.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [:first-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

```
select:first-child {
  width: 50%;
}
```